# lightdm-gtk-greeter power and settings indicator show no icon

Tags: lightdm

I installed Ubuntu mini 12.10 and then I did `apt-get install lxde-core lightdm-gtk-greeter`.

I successfully changed the LightDM screen resolution editing the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and adding `display-setup-script=xrandr -s 1280x720`.

How to add an image for the power and settings icons in the lightdm-gtk-greeter screen? Right now, it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your *lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf* or *lightdm-gtk-greeter-ubuntu.conf* file:

```
[greeter]
icon-theme-name=Humanity
```

Comment: I tried adding these lines to /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf. Not fixed yet. I'm assuming there should be icon files somewhere for this theme to work and I'm not having them in my disk.  I already have `theme-name=Ambiance` in the file so, I tried adding `icon-theme-name=Ambiance`. That also did not help. Have any idea where these icon files are supposed to be located for the theme to work? Or can we add a new theme manually? meanwhile, let me also look for the documentation if there is any.

Comment: The icon theme, should be in _/usr/share/icons_.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I see only 2 folders here, hicolor and nuoveXT2. Is that normal? 

**Note:** I  installed bare minimum OS using ubuntu-12.04.1-alternate-i386.iso

Comment: Then install _humanity-icon-theme_ or use a custom like _nuoveXT2_.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just did `sudo apt-get install humanity-icon-theme` and after rebooting, I have some icons on them, finally got a fix after 3+ months ) !! I really appreciate your help. [old-screen](http://db.tt/lk1MTOol) [fixed-screen](http://db.tt/r9b5ICAf)